# Cordova InAppBrowser 3.2.0 import of CDVUserAgentUtil breaks build and undeclared identifier '_settings'

Tags: ios, cordova

have had ongoing issues with the deprecated UIWebView which cordova ios@6.0.0 should have fixed.

I've been running into another issues post update, where in CDVWKInAppBrowser.m
line 27: #import  'Cordova/CDVUserAgentUtil.h' file not found

I took a look at master branch for InAppBrowser: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

and noticed the local is quite different in some lines? first, I'd like to identify if anyone else is having this issue?

I've followed the standard steps of:
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@3.2.0
cordova prepare ios
[cordova plugins ls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdgLn.png)

currently on ios platform 6.0.0
[cordova platform -ls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n8YB.png)

ultimately, i was trying to fix the issue outlined here:
[iOS] No known instance method for selector 'shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:' #714
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/714

In trying to fix this issue, replaced:
src/ios/CDVInAppBrowserNavigationController.m
src/ios/CDVWKInAppBrowser.m

with: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/666/commits/cd69af6d19b78c1176ffeafb4eb83ee0d5fd6f8f

but this in turn results in: Use of undeclared identifier '_settings' cordova.

[CDVInAppBrowser undeclared identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omqoI.png)
[_settings undeclared identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoTMx.png)

Comment: I realize the problem is a bit obscure and wanted to add some initial context;

Comment: I have the exact same problem with "CDVWKInAppBrowser.m line 27: #import 'Cordova/CDVUserAgentUtil.h' file not found" and trying to find a solution too...

Since the last release 3.2.0 is from January 2020, I will try to download the source code and add it as a plugin manually

Answer (score 11):

Since June 10th 2020, `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` has been upgraded to version `4.0.0` and has removed all code linked to the old UIWebView.

If you upgrade to `cordova-ios@6.0.0` and then do

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```

you will download the version `4.0.0` where errors like

```
CDVWKInAppBrowser.m line 27: #import 'Cordova/CDVUserAgentUtil.h' file not found
```

have been solved.

The release announcement can be found here: https://cordova.apache.org/news/2020/06/13/plugins-release.html

Here are the main points (copied from the announcement)

> The Cordova-iOS 6.x platform removes all UIWebView code and this version also removes the UIWebView code from the InAppBrowser plugin ( https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/635 )
>
> For backwards compatibility, this plugin used to hook window.open. However, the plugin-installed hook of window.open could have unintended side effects (especially if this plugin is included only as a dependency of another plugin) and it has been removed in this release. ( https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/599 )
>
> The InAppBrowser plugin used to implement its own status bar. It has been removed in this release to correctly display the content of the iOS status bar without overlapping the content in the InAppBrowser on different devices. ( https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/656 )